# Will a missing door check strap cause MOT failure (in the UK)?

Tags: door

A little while ago I managed to bend the driver's door back on my Ford Focus. The car is old enough that the cost of replacement panels would be more than the car is worth, so I got my friendly local body shop to bend the door back into shape and it's now fine. The door opens and closes normally and doesn't leak in the rain.

But the check strap was broken when the door was bent back, and the body shop didn't refit it (which is fair enough - I didn't ask them to). Googling suggests it's quite a fiddly job replacing the check strap and therefore probably quite expensive. So I'm wondering whether to just not bother since this is an old car (now with a crumpled door!) with a limited life.

The only problem is if the missing door check strap will be a cause for MOT failure, so I'd be grateful if someone can tell me whether it is or not.

Comment: Best option is check with a certified mot tester - as some things do have a discretionary element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [motester.co.uk](http://www.motester.co.uk/mot-information-for-motorists/mot-test-checks-list):

> MOT Test of Doors
>
> Both front doors must be openable from the inside and outside and all doors must latch securely.
>   a passenger door must open from the outside using relevant control
>   All door hinges, catches and pillars to be assessed for door readily opening and closing, and security
>
> Tailgates, bootlids etc.
>
> All these items, including the tailboards and dropsides of trucks must be securable in the closed position.

This suggests to me that it would not be a fail, unless the tester decided that it affects the security of the door - but I think that's more about making sure that the door can't open accidentally, which the check strap doesn't affect.

As Solar Mike says, it's probably worth asking a tester...

Comment: Thanks Nick. It looks from your answer as if I'll be OK. I think the best option is just to wait and see what happens when the car is next MOT'd.